# How to fix this indentation error in Python?

Tags: python

I have no idea how to fix the indentation error in line 12.

```
def cube(number):

    number=n
    cube(n)=n**3
    return cube(n)

def by_three(number):

    number=n

    if n%3==0:
    cube(number)
    return cube(number)


    else:
    return False
```

Comment: If your real code is indented like this no wonder you have problems

Comment: if - esle statement is not indented as expected

Comment: I submitted an edit of the question which should answer the question at the same time.

Comment: Just as you have indented your code within the functions `cube` and `by_three`, you need to correctly indent the code inside your `if` statement.

Comment: @JulienD - your edit would invalidate the question itself. This is not really a helpful edit. Edits should improve the **question**. To answer the question, just post an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning how to code. I'm just a kid. goosh

Comment: @JulienD DO NOT edit questions to correct the error the OP reports.

Comment: Thank you very much JulienD.

Answer (score 1):

More than indentation let me fix your code.

- you don't need number=n, you can directly use number instead of n.
  The more the number of lines in python, the overhead will increase.
- You can not do this cube(n)=n**3, assignment to function. It's illegal.

> ```
> def cube(n):
>     return n**3
> def by_three(n): 
>     if n%3==0:
>         return cube(n)
>     else:
>         return False
> ```